# Is there no way to directly save the token found in the request header?

Tags: reactjs, axios, oauth

I'm currently working on a project in a bootcamp.

I'm in charge of the login feature, and I need to implement it quickly in order to move on to other features. However, no matter how much I search, I can't find a solution, so I'm struggling.

The current situation is as follows:

When you click the Google Login button,

```js
export const GoogleBtn = () => {
  const googleSocialLogin = () => {
    window.location.href = `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/oauth2/authorization/google`;
  };

  return (
    <OauthBtn
      bgColor="#f6f6f2"
      color="#2e2e2e"
      onClick={googleSocialLogin}
      icon={<FcGoogle className="googleicon" />}
      text="Log in with Google Account"
    />
  );
};
```

It takes you to the account selection page:
[image]

Upon selecting an account, one piece of information is received in Developer Tools -> Network when redirected to localhost:3000. (Corresponding to the part below 'google~~~'):
[image]

I want to store the access token and refresh token that come with the Authorization and Refresh headers in that information, but I don't know how to do it from here:
[image]

I would appreciate it if you could share your experiences!

I hope this helps!

I've spent half a day searching on Google, Korean communities, blogs, and more, but I couldn't find the answer .